# Merging these two tables is a good idea?

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance

i have those tables

```
    names                hobbies                  names_hobbies
| id |    name  |    | id |     hobby   |    | name_id | hobby_id |
|----|----------|    |----|-------------|    |---------|----------|
|  1 |    mark  |    |  1 |     diving  |    |  1      |  1       |
|  2 |    elvis |    |  2 |     running |    |  1      |  2       |
.................    ....................    ......................

    relatives                     names_relatives
| id |    relative  |    | name_id | relative_id |  type   | 
|----|--------------|    |---------|-------------|---------|
|  1 |    bruce     |    |  1      |  1          |  uncle  |
|  2 |    john      |    |  1      |  2          |  uncle  |
|  3 |    samuel    |    |  1      |  3          |  nephew |
|  4 |    rose      |    |  1      |  4          |  nephew |
|  5 |    jonathan  |    |  1      |  5          |  cousin |
.....................    ...................................
```

I have the main table named `names` and two other tables made to connect to it named `hobbies` and `relatives`, those tables are connected through `names_hobbies` and `names_relatives` and their construct is like this

```
        names                     hobbies                           relatives          
| id      |    name   |    | id      |     hobby    |    | id           |     relative    |
| primary |    index  |    | primary |     unique   |    | primary      |     index       |


            names_hobbies                                  names_relatives
        | name_id | hobby_id |                        | name_id | relative_id |
        |      unique        |                        |       unique          |
```

tables records are estimated like this

```
names: 100,000
hobbies: 60
relatives: 500,000
------------------
names_hobbies: 800,000 (names x 8 of hobbies)
names_relatives: 500,000 (names x 5 of relatives)
```

---

is it possible to optimize these tables?

i thought about merging `hobbies` and `relatives` into a single table named `connections`

then merging `names_hobbies` and `names_relatives` into a single table named `names_connections`

and since there is a `type` column i thought about adding `type = hobby` instead of just relatives types, any ideas?

as in

```
    connections                    names_connections      
| id |    connection  |    | name_id | connection_id |  type   | 
|----|----------------|    |---------|---------------|---------|
|  1 |    bruce       |    |  1      |  1            |  uncle  |
|  2 |    john        |    |  1      |  2            |  uncle  |
|  3 |    samuel      |    |  1      |  3            |  nephew |
|  4 |    rose        |    |  1      |  4            |  nephew |
|  5 |    jonathan    |    |  1      |  5            |  cousin |
|  6 |    diving      |    |  1      |  7            |  hobby  |
|  7 |    running     |    |  1      |  8            |  hobby  |
```

Comment: No. Hobbies and relatives look like they are totally different entities. Keep the tables as they are.

Comment: all relatives have a name, all hobbies have a name, so combine `name`, `hobbies` and `relatives` into a single table? while technically possible to combine tables, at some point it may be confusing ... juggling different `types`,adding (future) columns that only apply to certain `types`, etc; having said that ... I could see combining `names` and `relatives` into a single table (`people`), then change `names_relatives` to just `relatives`; don't forget: bruce is mark's uncle; mark is bruce's nephew => duplicate entries in `names/relatives`? or single entries in `people`?

Comment: @markp the `people` table actually exists but the `names_relatives` is for the unregistered relatives names that is connected if they registered, so the only think i can manipulate is `names_hobbies` and `names_relatives`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ they both are just names, it can be merged and defining the hobbies using the same `type` column in relatives but instead of just family-types i would add `hobby` as the name of type to it, do i still keep them separated but the problem is that hobbies key is `unique` but relatives is `index`?

Comment: Advice has been asked for and you're not listening, why is that? You've added a question mark but there isn't a question. Unique and primary keys are both types of indexes.

Comment: +1 for the innovative way to describe the table and their indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hobbies and relatives are different things.  Two separate tables.

Names and relatives are both 'people' -- a single table should suffice.

"Name" is quite generic, just as "id" is.  If you called it `first_and_last_name`, then it would no longer sound like the "name" of a "hobbie".

Approach schema design from this point of view:

Entities:  One table for each: persons and hobbies.

1:many Relationships:  no extra table is needed.

many:many Relationships:  then a 2-column table is needed for each.  Or more columns, as with 'type' of relation, such as 'nephew'.  Note:  It is a waste to have an `id` purely for such tables.  You need two such tables -- person_hobby and person_person.

Why not lump hobbies and persons together?  You will, someday, have columns in `persons` (phone number, address, birthday, etc) that have no meaning for hobbies.  And vice versa.